# Adding contact-page at the end of the page using react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

##### Current Page

[image]

#### Expected Page

[image]

I want to add a form in the yellow marked area when I click the order page and the URL should change to /contact/contact-form. Can anyone please help with this issue.

Code : https://github.com/devgobind/burger-builder

Comment: I would suggest reading the docs for react-router this seems pretty easy and only thing you need to do is just adding the current page as common element and a reactrouter conditional loading code to check the URL and based on the URL change just display the form after it. Remember you will learn more if you try to figure out this yourself if you are still stuck then you can mention.

Comment: Create a new wrapper component which will render on router change and inside that new component use these burgar components internally.

Comment: @innocent I am reading the documentation currently. I know how to add this in react-router v5 but in v6 there are many new things added and old tags removed.